# Rtools35 gcc.exe missing in windows

Tags: r, gcc, rtools

Just installed [Rtools35](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) with Admin rights and all options checked:

[image]

and running:

```
> Sys.which("ls.exe")
                   ls.exe 
"C:\\Rtools\\bin\\ls.exe"
> Sys.which("gcc.exe")
gcc.exe 
     ""
```

I also manually looked inside 'C:\Rtools\bin\' and gcc.exe is missing. Can't build packages.

Attempt using `installr`.

```
library(installr)
> install.rtools()
Loading required namespace: devtools
No need to install Rtools - You've got the relevant version of Rtools installed
```

Also, uninstalled, restarted and reinstalled just to be sure.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.19
```

Comment: Look in C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\gcc.exe for the 64 bit version and C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin\gcc.exe for the 32 bit version.

Comment: Aha! That's where it is. Thanks :-)